# Django form doesn't output custom class attributes for inputs

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I'm trying to use ModelForms to output forms with custom CSS classes:

urls.py:

```
url(r'^mymodel/add/$',
    MyModelCreate.as_view(template_name='add_MyModel.html'),
    name='mymodel-add')
```

views.py:

```
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from myapp.models import MyModel
class MyModelCreate(CreateView):
  model=MyModel
  def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context=super(MyModelUpdate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['css'] = settings.CSS_PATH
    return context
```

I've tried overriding the base ModelForm's **init** and looping over all the fields:

```
class MyBaseForm(forms.ModelForm):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
      super(MyBaseForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
      for key in self.fields:
          self.fields[key].widget.attrs.update(
                                        {'class' : 'field-class',
                                        'placeholder':self.fields[key].label
                                        })
```

I've tried setting the Form class's `formfield_callback` to add a default class:

```
def add_field_classes(f, **kwargs):
  field = f.formfield(**kwargs)
  if field:
      w = field.widget
      if 'class' not in field.widget.attrs:
          field.widget.attrs['class'] = ''
      field.widget.attrs['class'] += ' form_class'
      if isinstance(w, forms.widgets.SelectMultiple):
          field.widget.attrs['class'] += ' multiselect'
  return field

class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
  formfield_callback=add_field_classes
```

...and I've tried setting attrs through widgets:

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    fields = ('field1',)
    widgets={'field1':forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'field-class'}),}
```

No matter what I do, the template outputs the widgets without any classes; I've tried just using `{{form}}` and I've tried looping over fields with `{{for field in form}}{{endfor}}`

If I create a form instance and template using `manage.py shell` and render it, it includes the classes so I suspect there must be something happening with the view level.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use your custom form in your view. If you don't specify a form_class for CreateView, django will create one for you:

```
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from myapp.models import MyModel

class MyModelCreate(CreateView):
  model=MyModel
  form_class = MyBaseForm
  def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context=super(MyModelUpdate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['css'] = settings.CSS_PATH
    return context
```